# Is there any way to know which Bible version is correct about 1 John 5:7-8?

Tags: bible, truth, version, accuracy

Some Bible versions say that there are three witnesses in heaven and that is **The Father**, **The Son** and **The Spirit.**

**1 John 5:7-8**

> there are three witnesses in heaven: the Father, the Word and the Holy Spirit, and these three are One

While others talk about the witnesses being the **blood**, the **water** and the **spirit**.

**1 John 5:7-8**

> For there are three that testify: the Spirit and the water and the blood; and these three agree

Should Christians believe the versions that read similar to the second one because of what happened during the crucifixion. Jesus' left rib was pierced then blood and water proceeded forth from the wound.

**John 19:34**

> But one of the soldiers pierced his side with a spear, and at once there came out blood and water.

Comment: It is agreed by many that the 'Johannine Comma' should not be included in scripture. The very wording linking 'Father' and 'Word' is quite clearly inappropriate. Erasmus was prevailed upon to include it only due to a Latin (not Greek) manuscript being located.

Comment: @NigelJ, did Erasmus erroneously introduce that part or is it because a Latin version containing that text existed already?

Comment: @NigelJ, I invited you to a private Bible discussion chat on Google Chat, hopefully you will accept it, Thanks and may God bless you.

Comment: @NigelJ, if you google search 'Google Chat' , it will open a chat window with the message I just sent.

Comment: Related:  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/17392/32868

Comment: @MikeBorden, Thanks for the link, so it was one verse , some versions have both verses? There are three that bear witness in heaven and three that bear witness on earth

Comment: I believe that is correct.  The heavenly record of v. 7 is the disputed phrase and not the earthly witness of verse 8.

Comment: @MikeBorden, Thanks and what did Erasmus do? Did he do it intentionally?

Comment: You would have to ask him :)  While the verse is suspect, the Trinitarian theology it represents is not.  Nevertheless, it is best to label it as suspect, at best.  IMHO.

Comment: Catholic opinion was in favour of including the 'comma'. Erasmus had no Greek manuscript containing the wording but then he was somewhhat restricted in his access to all the relevant data. Catholic opinion desired the 'Trinitarian support' (despite that the linking of 'Father' and 'Word' is unscriptural and not logical). A Latin manuscript was dug up and Erasmus gave in and included the comma. One can understand both his misgivings and his reluctance to be at variance. They were difficult times.

Comment: @NigelJ, but if he accepted his mistake and repented then it's not a big deal. _A latin manuscript was dug up and he gave Erasmus gave in and included the comma_, the truth has a way of coming out